# set permalink multiple pages visited

Tags: php, html, css, url, permalinks

I am creating a web site with multiple pages, this is the url for example.

```
    www.example.com/gallery
```

The gallery page is perfect but on visiting second page the url change to

```
www.example.com/second-page
```

it should be

```
www.example.com/gallery/second-page
```

in URl tab

on visiting another page
url turn to
    www.example.com/gallery/second-page/etc/etc/etc

please help me

how to set permalinks properly

Comment: why would you want this behaviour?

Comment: You could use rewrite rules in .htacess for this (based on my understanding of your question).

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with the name of the `gallery` in your hosting. Then rename the `gallery` page with the `index` name and place it inside the `gallery` folder. Likewise with `second-page` pages also placed in the `gallery` folder.